# Is it possible to set Angular Material 13 datepicker input format to match locale?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular13

I have datepicker in mat-form-field:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>label</mat-label>
    <input
      [max]="endDate"
      [ngModel]="startDate"
      (click)="pickerFrom.open();"
      readonly
      matInput
      [matDatepicker]="pickerFrom"
    />
    <mat-datepicker #pickerFrom></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

It works as intended, but in input date is always displayed in 'en-US' locale, which is default as far as I know.

Is it even possible to show dynamic date format based on user's system using Angular Material datepicker?

Regular mat-input with `dataType='data'` without Angular Material's datepicker works, but together creates a conflicts - after choosing date, logic behind datepicker throws an error that it is in wrong format.

I know there is possibility to change format by providing `MAT_DATE_FORMATS` or `MAT_DATE_LOCALE`, but it changes only to given format, not dynamically based on user's system.

I tried to switch between moment and native DataAdapters, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read the documentation about Anguar i18n and the datepicker.

```js
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import FR from '@angular/common/locales/fr';

registerLocaleData(FR);

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr-FR' },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR' },
  ]
  // ...
})
```

Comment: it sets locale to 'fr-FR' for all users who could have another one

Comment: You're supposed to provide the locales according to the language of your current build, not according to the language of the user. If the user is on the EN build, you provide the EN format. This is how i18n is supposed to work in Angular.

Comment: in this scenario language is not the main concern, only date format. On Windows one can change date format without changing language. Majority of users of the application which contains this snippet uses that OS

Comment: I stand by my previous statement. If it does not suit you, a custom implementation will be required, nothing exists for your needs.